# exchange 2010 sp1 - mailbox export stuck in queue

Tags: exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

I have been trying to export a few mailboxes for the past 2 days with only 1 sucessful export.
I'm currently trying to export an archive of a user but it stays "queued" even tho there are no other export requests:
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-MailboxExportRequestStatistics -Identity Cam.Ansell\mailboxexport1

```
Name                                   Status                    SourceAlias                           PercentComplete
----                                   ------                    -----------                           ---------------
MailboxExport1                         Queued                    cansell                               0
```

any ideas how to force it to start it?

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting the MS Exchange Mailbox Replication service on the CAS server.